# Adding Mother's and Father's day into Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

The Australian holidays calendar doesn't appear to include Mother's Day or Father's day. How can I add them into my calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has fantastic calendars available in iCal format:

- [Australian Holiday Calendar - New South Wales (NSW) 1.0](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/australianholidaycalendarnewsouthwalesnsw.html)
- [Australian Holiday Calendar and Key Dates - Tasmania (TAS) 1.0](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/australianholidaycalendarandkeydatestasmaniatas.html)

Both of these say that they have Mother's and Father's Day. Since they are in iCal format, you can [easily subscribe](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37100) to these calendars.

Comment: Do you know how far into the future it will work?

Comment: @Casebash: It should work indefinitely, since it will presumably be updated by Apple constantly.

Comment: Broken Apple links?

Answer (score 22):

To create events that occur annually on, say, the second Sunday of May, do this:

- Create an untimed event on May 8, 2011
- Open event details
- Change the "Repeats" value to "Monthly"
- Change to "Repeats every 12 months"
- Click the "Repeat By" radio button for "day of the week"
- Leave "Ends Never" as is

You now have a calendar event that will repeat the 2nd Sunday of May every year.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed if it was possible then you would have to set the repeats to yearly

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are omitted because they aren't national / regional holidays. You can add them to one of your personal calendars by adding them as with any other event. So that they look the same, you could create a new calender (called "Special days" or something) and make it have the same colour scheme as the built-in calendar - you'll barely notice the difference.

If you *really* want all these things in one calendar, I think the only way to do it is by creating your own then copying the ones from the main holidays calendar across.

In case it helps, here's the dates for the next few years (for Australia):

- 2011 - May 08
- 2012 - May 13
- 2013 - May 12
- 2014 - May 11

Looks to me like it's the second Sunday in May in Australia - you can program that in to Google Calendar (Annual recurrence on second Sunday in May). According to [this page](http://mothersday.indiangiftsportal.com/when-is-mothers-day.html) that is indeed the right way to go about it...

Comment: The date changing is the annoying aspect. It means I can't just program it in and forget it

Comment: @Casebash: you could program it in and set a notification to program the next year ...

Comment: Adding possible calculation to the answer...

Comment: Google actually doesn't let you program that in :-(

Comment: You certainly can add a recurring event based on the X Yday of the month. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it rigorously, but this seems to work -

[image: Mother's day Aus gcal]

Comment: Ooops, somehow missed Al E.'s answer above.