# How to add UK Mothering Sunday and Father's Day to Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I use Google calendar and the "Holidays in the United Kingdom" calendar doesn't include Mother's Day (in the UK) and Father's Day as they are not actual holidays.

Is it possible to add events for Mothering Sunday and Father's Day ? As they occur on different days of the month each year (ie. third Sunday in June for Father's day and three weeks before Easter Sunday for Mother's Day).

Comment: Duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/75213/354

Comment: Father's Day is easy, since it's the "Xth day of a specific month". See: [Adding Mother's and Father's day into Google Calendar](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1473/354). Mothering Sunday is significantly harder (if not impossible) because it's based on Easter, which changes every year. It can be worked out programmatically, but not in a way you could do in the Google Calendar interface.

Answer (score 1):

I personally just input all the dates manually until I'd be about 100 or so. Input them on a computer using a phone to reference the page if you don't want to be 100 or so when you're finished. :) Annoying, but it went by quite quickly once I figured out the fastest way of getting it done. https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/uk/mothering-sunday

Comment: Holy mothering Sunday, you have a lot of patience.